# Setting properties of FlowPlayer dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, flowplayer

I'm using Flow Player in ASP.NET Web Forms (VS 2010) and want to set some of its properties, like autoPlay, dynamically (read from a config file). But autoPlay don’t seem to be set dynamically. For example, the following code with autoPlay set to true (or false) works correctly:

function initialize() {

```
            player = flowplayer("flowPlayer", "<%=HttpType %>://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.15.swf", {
                key: '#$b9299630d834a59dcb9',
                clip: {
                    autoPlay: true,
                    autoBuffering: true,
                    scaling: 'fit',
                    onFinish: function () {

                    }
                },
                canvas: {
                    // configure background properties
                    background: '#000000',
                    // remove default canvas gradient
                    backgroundGradient: 'none'
                }
            });
        }
```

However, obtaining the value AutoPlay from code-behind (which would obtain a value from a config file) doesn’t work. Is there a better way to set the value dynamically? I can’t find online documentation that addresses setting these value dynamically:

```
                            function initialize() {

            player = flowplayer("flowPlayer", "<%=HttpType %>://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.15.swf", {
                key: '#$b9299630d834a59dcb9',
                clip: {
                    autoPlay: <%=AutoPlay%>,
                    autoBuffering: true,
                    scaling: 'fit',
                    onFinish: function () {

                    }
                },
                canvas: {
                    // configure background properties
                    background: '#000000',
                    // remove default canvas gradient
                    backgroundGradient: 'none'
                }
            });
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<body/>

<div id="player" class="fixed-controls"></div>

HTML
<script>

$(function() { // make sure the DOM is ready
  $("#player").flowplayer({
    ratio: 5/12,
    rtmp: "rtmp://s3b78u0kbtx79q.cloudfront.net/cfx/st",
    playlist: [
      [
        { webm:  "http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus.webm" },
        { mp4:   "http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus.mp4" },
        { flash: "mp4:bauhaus" }
      ]
    ]
    }).one('ready', function(ev, api) {
      api.resume();
    });
});
```